# Create link using font-awesome in a span- and i-tag in html

Tags: html

I am trying to create a link from some font-awesome icons within a span- and i-tag, however, this does not work. I am using the following code:

```
        <a href="mailto:?subject=Test&amp;body=Test">
          <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the version of stylesheet, Sometimes they do misbehave

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css">
 
<a href="mailto:?subject=Test&amp;body=Test">
          <span class="fa fa-stack fa-4x">
              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>
</a>
```

You may also try to change referencing to the minified version to uncompressed version. It will all depends.

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine you need to add font-awesome.css file and font folder

Comment: Everything is rendering fine, so the css is not the problem

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to layer all 3 of the icons?

Comment: Yes, I am trying that